# display my custom stock messages only if variable product is managing stock

Tags: php, woocommerce

I have code that works to total the stock of all variations of a product and then display messages based on that number.
BUT when the variable product is NOT set to manage stock, at both the product and the variation level I want it to display nothing.
Currently my code displays the 'sorry I am sold out!' message at the category page level if manage stock is not checked. At the single product page it displays 'Only Available' with no number when a variation is selected. I suspect because $stock_quantity in my code is returning null?
These products are a special case as they are custom order and as such do not use stock levels.

I tried wrapping my code in the if below so that products not managing stock would be excluded but it did not work.

```
if ( $product->managing_stock() ){
// so code in here only runs for products set to manage stock
}
```

This was my full code......

```
//VARIABLE PRODUCTS ADDITION OF ALL VARIATIONS STOCK FOR TOTAL STOCK
function wc_get_variable_product_stock_quantity( $output = 'raw', $product_id = 0 ){
    global $wpdb, $product;

    // Get the product ID (can be defined)
    $product_id = $product_id > 0 ? $product_id : get_the_id();

    // Check and get the instance of the WC_Product Object
    $product = is_a( $product, 'WC_Product' ) ? $product : wc_get_product($product_id);
    if ( $product->managing_stock() ){
    // Only for variable product type
    if( $product->is_type('variable')){

        // Get the stock quantity sum of all product variations (children)
        $stock_quantity = $wpdb->get_var("
            SELECT SUM(pm.meta_value)
            FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts as p
            JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta as pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id
            WHERE p.post_type = 'product_variation'
            AND p.post_status = 'publish'
            AND p.post_parent = '$product_id'
            AND pm.meta_key = '_stock'
            AND pm.meta_value IS NOT NULL
        ");

        // Preparing formatted output
        if (($stock_quantity <= 5) && ( $stock_quantity > 0)) {
            $html = '<p class="stock in-stock">'. __('Only ' .$stock_quantity. ' Available!', 'babasouk').'</p>';
        } else {
            if ( $stock_quantity == 0 )
                $html = '<p class="stock out-of-stock">' . __('Sorry, I am sold out!', 'babasouk') . '</p>';
            else
                $html = '';
        }

        // Different output options
        if( $output == 'echo_html' )
            echo $html;
        elseif( $output == 'return_html' )
            return $html;
        else
            return $stock_quantity;
    }
        }
} 
// END VARIABLE PRODUCTS ADDITION OF ALL VARIATIONS STOCK FOR TOTAL STOCK

// DISPLAY VARIABLE STOCK SHOP PAGE
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'display_variable_product_stock_quantity', 20 );
function display_variable_product_stock_quantity(){
    wc_get_variable_product_stock_quantity( 'echo_html' );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try wrapping your code in this if statement and let me know if it works.

```
if ( get_post_meta( $product_id, '_manage_stock', true ) == "yes"){
// so code in here only runs for products set to manage stock
}
```

Comment: It did not work. It did change things. On a category page products which do not have manage stock set no longer show "sorry I am sold out!" BUT products that do have it set and are actually out of stock display nothing either. The "Only x available" message also does not display. Single product pages for variable products remain unaffected.

Comment: When you remove the if statement, what shows up for products that have mange stock set and are out of stock?

Comment: Without your if statement when stock IS managed, on the category & shop pages.    
if all variations are out of stock 'Sorry, I am sold out!'  
If one is out of stock the message is based on stock level of the others.  
If combined stock is 5 or less ‘Only x available’ Even if one is sold out and another has 5 in stock.  

On the individual product pages…  
each variation displays the appropriate message for that variation after it is selected from the dropdown.  
That is as I want it.   
NON stock managed products should show no messages at all. Sorry I can not make comment formatting